# An affine characterization of ellipsoids?

Tags: convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a convex body of volume 1 in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x$ a (variable) point on the boundary of $K$. Define $f_K(x)$ to be the volume of the convex hull of the union of $K$ with its reflection in $x$, that is,

$$f_K(x)=\rm{Vol}\left\{\rm{Conv}\left[K\cup(2x-K)\right]\right\}.$$

It is easy to see that for an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid $E$, the function $f_E(x)$ is constant, $f_E=e_n$, depending on $n$ only:

[image]

$\displaystyle e_n=1+{{2\sigma_{n-1}\over{\sigma_n}}}$,  where $\sigma_k$ denotes the volume of the $k$-dimensional unit ball.

**Question 1.** If $f_K(x)$ is a constant function, must $K$ be an ellipsoid?

**Question 1a.** If $f_K(x)$ is a constant function, must $K$ be centrally symmetric?

**Question 1b.** If $K$ ***is*** centrally symmetric ***and*** $f_K(x)$ is a constant function, must $K$ be an ellipsoid?

**Question 2.** Is $\displaystyle e_n=\max_K\left[\,\min_{x\,\in\, bdK}\,f_K(x)\right]$? (Here the maximum is taken over all $n$-dimensional convex bodies $K$ of volume 1.)

If the answer to either of these questions is known, a reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The case $n=2$ may be more tractable -- what happens there?

Comment: I believe the answer is "yes"; the lower the dimension the stronger my belief.

Comment: May I ask you to expand a bit on "It is easy to see..."?

Comment: The question is invariant under linear transformations, so it's enough to do the case of a sphere, which is clear by symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, just an illustration.

---

[image: ThreeEllipses]

          

<sup>Three $2 \times 1$ ellipses, rotated $30^\circ$, reflected through different points. Hulls have the same area.</sup>

---

Comment: Nice drawing. This works for ellipsoids in every dimension.

Comment: These are nice drawings — but I’d like them better as edits to the post than as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some partial answers in this paper

A.G. Horváth, Z.Lángi, On the volume of the convex hull of two convex bodies, Monat. fur Mathematic 174, pp 219-229
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00605-013-0526-x